# ng add @angular/fire error Cannot run login in non-interactive mode

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

When I run:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

I get this error:

```
$ ng add @angular/fire
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1542 bytes)
- Installing packages (npm)...
✔ Packages installed successfully.
Cannot run login in non-interactive mode. See login:ci to generate a token for use in non-interactive environments.
```

I am running this on Windows 10 Pro Git Bash.

This failure is causing other errors, e.g. `ng deploy` fails because `ng add @angular/fire` fails to update `angular.json` with a deploy target. Any ideas what the problem is? many thanks

Running on `Node v14.17.1` and `@angular/cli v11.2.14`

Comment: Have you tried using windows cmd? Lately i've had many issues with git bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is a Windows issue.

Instead of:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

Run:

```
winpty node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd add @angular/fire
```

If that fails then try:

```
npx firebase login --interactive // firebase should have been installed locally when the previous command failed
winpty node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd add @angular/fire
```

Also, instead of:

```
ng deploy
```

Run:

```
winpty node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd deploy
```

Finally, you probably want to update your package.json deploy script to look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "deploy": "ng deploy",
  "deploy:win": "winpty node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd deploy"
},
```

Decent OS users can deploy with `npm run deploy` and Windows users can deploy with `npm run deploy:win`